# One-to-many connection, several tables sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've got some tables

**tech_map** (17 rows):
*id,name,status, id_user_add, datetime_add, commentary*

**tech_map_expenses** (7 rows):
*id,name,cost, tech_map.id*

**tech_map_products** (8 rows):
*id,category_id,catalog_id, total, tech_map_id*

**tech_map_stock** (8 rows):
*id,category_id,catalog_id, total, tech_map_id*

And I want to select tech_map where exits connection with other tables
for example:

```
SELECT tech_map.* 
FROM 
`tech_map`
INNER JOIN tech_map_expenses ON tech_map_expenses.tech_map_id = tech_map.id
INNER JOIN tech_map_products ON tech_map_products.tech_map_id = tech_map.id
INNER JOIN tech_map_stock ON tech_map_stock.tech_map_id = tech_map.id 
ORDER BY tech_map.id DESC
```

But it's return too many rows (33) with duplicate records.

Comment: Are you kidding...? How do you expect is to understand where the problem is? Minimize the problem, add sample table data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the Left Join to a Inner Join. Why?

- Left Join will contain only all the tech_map that doesnt have a
  connection with the other tables.
- Inner Join will contain only all the tech_map that have a connection
  with the other tables.

Take a look at this [picture](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg), it always help me.

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: Edited with the explanation!

Comment: but its not working because its return too many records with duplicate value :(((( P.s. in tables duplicate values aren't exist

Comment: Because when you join the table, you're joining multiple rows to a singular row. This will show the singular row multiple times with the different multiple rows appended. e.g. if A had one row, and B had 2, you'd have A-B1 and A-B2. You need to either `GROUP BY tech_map.id` for the correct (of the multiple) rows, or  understand that's how the output will be.

Comment: @Rogue is correct, you should now check the result and see if you must a group by to fit the result the way you wants

Comment: For example to understand my problem: tech_map.id it is shops. tech_map_stock AND tech_map_products , tech_map_expenses- it is some products and prices. So I want to know how many in the store the goods, what their price, what remains. That is, there is one-to-many relationship here. Goods, prices, balances can be several